# Unrecognised argument error when trying to run dbt with no version check

Tags: dbt

I am new to dbt and I am trying to run dbt freshness test but I seem to be getting errors.

the below code has been working successfully

```
dbt run --no-version-check
```

But when I try to run this

```
 dbt source freshness --no-version-check
```

I get the following error

```
usage: dbt [-h] [--version] [-r RECORD_TIMING_INFO] [-d] [--log-format {text,json,default}] [--no-write-json]
           [--use-colors | --no-use-colors] [--printer-width PRINTER_WIDTH] [--warn-error] [--no-version-check]
           [--partial-parse | --no-partial-parse] [--use-experimental-parser] [--no-static-parser]
           [--profiles-dir PROFILES_DIR] [--no-anonymous-usage-stats] [-x] [--event-buffer-size EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE]
           {docs,source,init,clean,debug,deps,list,ls,build,snapshot,run,compile,parse,test,seed,run-operation}
           ...
dbt: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-version-check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
dbt --no-version-check source freshness
```